# How to create unsigned ipa file using xcode 12.4? Unable to install "Runner"? code: Code: -402620388

Tags: ios, flutter, runner

```
Unable to install "Runner"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388
how to solved it.
```

Details

[image]

### Unable to install "Runner"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388

No code signature found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388
User Info:

```
{
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE800801C)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012c305c8f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012c344241 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c90864b DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012c343f82 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012c1b4a10 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ca3717e __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ca38da0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2016b5dd _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2016c7c7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201725fe _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201730cb _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2017cc5d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20314499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20313467 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

System Information

macOS Version 11.0.1 (Build 20B29)
Xcode 12.4 (17801) (Build 12D4e)
Timestamp: 2021-03-20T01:25:23-07:00

I am new in flutter. how to it solved?

Comment: When is this happening. What command are you trying to run? Please try to be more explicit to make it easier to help you.

Comment: when i build from xcode

Comment: Try building from terminal.

Comment: i have created unsigned ipa file from terminal. but it is not clickable install file in iPhone.

Comment: Any one help me. How to creat unsigned ipa file?

Comment: @Nougat, you can't install an unsigned application into an iOS device. But you can create a free developer account and sign it (aka. set a provisioning profile to your app). Maybe this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running your app on your device (e.g. Mac, iPad, or iPhone?), as opposed to a Simulator? On StackOverflow, try to give as much detail as possible, that's why `lenz` meant. *It seems like you're building a Flutter app to run on iPhone, **not** your macbook?*

Have a read of [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running_your_app_in_the_simulator_or_on_a_device), especially (but not only), the "Select a Real Device" section.

### If building for your iOS device:

> If you choose a real device, add your Apple ID in Accounts preferences and assign the project to a team on the Signing & Capabilities pane of the project editor. A single individual constitutes a one-person team. For macOS apps, you need to code sign the app if you enable certain capabilities. If you belong to the Apple Developer Program, you need to register the device before you can run the app.

You need to

- log into Xcode with your Apple ID. You **don't** need the $99 Apple Developer program membership.
- Check automatically manage signing in "Signing and Capabilities" tab

### If you're building for macOS (not mobile app):

If you're building a macOS app without signing it, either:

- **Disable** code signing: follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039513/how-can-i-skip-code-signing-for-development-builds-in-xcode)
- **Code sign** it: follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341755/how-to-sign-mac-os-x-application)

Comment: i want to unsigned ipa file using xcode 12.4

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54296008/7365866) work? :), also please confirm more details: device or emulator? Which device (macOS, iOS are you building for)?

Comment: By any chance, are you building for a mac instead of your iOS emulator or iPhone device? Change the device in the toolbar to your iOS device. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61639448/7365866) shows you how.

Comment: runner requires a development team. select a development team in the signing & capabilities editor

Comment: Yes you can create a team, you should do that.

Comment: i make only unsigned ipa file not signed ipa file

Comment: You still need a team to build an app onto a device

Comment: build input file cannot be found ::........................ios/OptizizationProfile/Runner.profdata

Comment: Hey Nougat, please update your question with as much detail as possible. It is hard for me (and others) to digest your situation through the comments

Comment: Does this work? :), also please confirm more details: device or emulator? Which device (macOS, iOS are you building for)? @Ben Butterworth

Comment: i use xcode 12.4 you can me help for unsign ipa file create, how to create unsigned ipa file using xcode 12.4

Comment: if you help me. and i solved my problem. then i accept your answer.@Ben Butterworth

Comment: just i want unsigned ipa file.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I have been a little busy. I have written another comment to your question, try that :)

Comment: i dont solve my problem, but i accept your answer. please   talk me how i make unsign ipa file using xcode 12.4.

Comment: please help me, how to make unsigned ipa file.

Comment: Did you read my other comment: have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak TLDR: you need to create a provisioning profile on Xcode

Comment: i will inform you tommarow

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to reflect our conversation, let me know if you need more help

Comment: dear brother, i inform you, now i am week.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: may be i am affected covid-19.

Comment: so i am rested in home.

Comment:   oh my, good luck, I am happy to help when you are ready. 

Comment: Are you ready for make update answer for this question?

Comment: Do you have further information, I can try to help

Comment: i want 3 thinks, 1) create new apps hello world, 2) create unsigned ipa file using xcode via product=> achieve  3) create clickable install file which click then install directly in iphone.

Comment: i want 3 thinks, 1) create new apps hello world, 2) create unsigned ipa file using xcode via product=> achieve  3) create clickable install file using https://www.diawi.com/ which click then install directly in iphone.

Comment: You can't do that, its a security feature by Apple. You need to sign your app to be able to install it on a device. To install it on devices that don't belong to you, you need to be on ADP (Apple developer program)